# Is there anything like Extension Functions for Java or other popular languages?

Tags: java, kotlin

In Kotlin, we have a beautiful feature like Extension.
Where even a newer custom method can be added to the super class whose object has been instantiated. That method can be accessed by the object created in the code.

My question is basically forked into two.

1. Were there any concept of this feature in Java or other popularly used programming languages?
2. If the previous answer is **no**, are there any kind of workaround to implement extensions in Java or other languages?

Comment: not entirely sure, but I think the lombok project implemented something like this.

Comment: This feature exists in a very similar form in C#.

Comment: I'd just add that it has existed in C# for a decade, introduced in 2007.

Answer (score 6):

Currently there seems to be no feature in java to provide such functionality, however Lombok provides us with alternative by using `@ExtensionMethod` annotation to extend api without extending classes. There is example provided on their web page:

https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/ExtensionMethod

As you can see this feature is experimental though ...

Answer (score 1):

**Swift** has very similar extensions functionality. You can find more on them [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html).

If you look, what extension functions in Kotlin compile to, you will see, that they are good old Java static methods with receiver as the first parameter, so I guess the best way how to do this in java is using static methods.

Comment: Swift and Kotlin seems to be quite similar in my limited explore so far!

Comment: They indeed are, unfortunately, Kotlin is very limited by Java underneath. For instance, Swift has much better generics, in terms accessing the type of generic parameter etc. Kotlin has "only" `reified` keyword, but it is also just a hack, when you look under the hood (I am not complaining! I'm glad that we have at least this, again, because of java)

Answer (score 0):

Extension methods are possible in many dynamic languages. In most dynamic languages, extension methods are usually called [monkey patching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch). For example, in [python](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2008-January/076194.html).

Answer (score 0):

We have extension in C# and D language, and we have implicit methods in Scala that can simulate such language feature.

In Ruby you can even define methods for an object, without affecting any other objects which are of the same type.